# Copy and Paste a table to main sheet from another sheet using

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have a dashboard and I would like to have a main sheet that summarize some name that I want to search for, so all my data are in other sheets.

I am trying to copy and past a table from data sheet to the main sheet. I´ve tried using =Vlookup and =xlookup, but it didn't wor. Now I am trying to use VBA.

First of all the data sheet is:

[Data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VZAQ.png)

I would like to copy and past data from I3:M6 (data sheet) if what I am searching for is "name1" in main sheet. On the other hand, if I want to search for "name2" I need to copy I9:M12 (data sheet) and so on.

the table 2 on main sheet nee just the data from the data sheet:

[main sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMGIF.png)

With that in mind, I´ve tried to create a VBA:

```
Sub table()

Dim i As Long, j as long
Dim wsMain As Worksheet, wsRV2 As Worksheet

  Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("main") 
 Set wsRV2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rv")

   For i = 2 To 250 Step 6 'loop in increments of 15
        For j = 9 To 10 Step 1

            If wsRV2.Cells(i, 8) = wsMain.Cells(4, 3) Then
            wsMain.Cells(12, 28) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 1, j)
            wsMain.Cells(12, 29) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 1, j + 1)
            wsMain.Cells(12, 30) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 1, j + 2)
            wsMain.Cells(12, 31) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 1, j + 3)
            wsMain.Cells(12, 32) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 1, j + 4)
            wsMain.Cells(13, 28) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 2, j)
            wsMain.Cells(13, 29) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 2, j + 1)
            wsMain.Cells(13, 30) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 2, j + 2)
            wsMain.Cells(13, 31) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 2, j + 3)
            wsMain.Cells(13, 32) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 2, j + 4)
            wsMain.Cells(14, 28) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 3, j)
            wsMain.Cells(14, 29) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 3, j + 1)
            wsMain.Cells(14, 30) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 3, j + 2)
            wsMain.Cells(14, 31) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 3, j + 3)
            wsMain.Cells(14, 32) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 3, j + 4)
            wsMain.Cells(15, 28) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 4, j)
            wsMain.Cells(15, 29) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 4, j + 1)
            wsMain.Cells(15, 30) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 4, j + 2)
            wsMain.Cells(15, 31) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 4, j + 3)
            wsMain.Cells(15, 32) = wsRV2.Cells(i + 4, j + 4)
            End If

        Next j
    Next i

end sub
```

i = line and j = column

If wsRV2.Cells(i, 8) = wsMain.Cells(4, 3) Then -->> if name1, name 2 ... is the same for both sheets

I know it is not the best way to do it by far (and it is not working). What am I doing wrong? If there´s a way to do it using excel function instead using vba I would like to know as well. I accept both solutions. Thank you so muchhh!

Comment: This could be done with formulas or vba. It looks like your code is just going to look at the same code over and over again... while using too many lines to accomplish the task. 1) post a couple pictures of base data and expected output so the community can better follow. 2) Try using the following tools to reduce lines: `cells(#, #).*offset*(#, #).value = cells(#, #).value`, `cells(#, #).*resize*(1,5).value ...`, 3) I don't think you need 2 nested for functions... Finally) if you have one contiguous range, `Range("A1:K500").Value = Range("A1:K500").Value`

Comment: If the range of the table for each name is consistent which is : it will always be in column H to column M and it always has 5 rows, then maybe you can set the range as the benchmark for the table. Example : `set rgMain = wsMain.range("AA11:AF15")`. Then find the cell in wsRV2 which contains the name you want to retrieve the data (it must be always in column HH of wsRV2) : `set c = wsRV2.range("H:H").find(wsMain.cells(4,3),lookat:=xlwhole)`.  Then fill the rgMain with c resized row and column : `rgMain.value = c.resize(rgMain.rows.count,rgMain.columns.count).value`